# На чем писать веб-сервис

Tags: веб-программирование, php, java

Ранее не сталкивался с веб-сервисами, не могу определится на чем его лучше реализовать `php` или `java`? 
В каких случаях лучше использовать `java`, а в каких `php`?
Заранее спасибо.

Нагрузка  ожидается не большая (дипломная работа), в ней действительно не существенно на чем писать, но ожидают несколько проектов с большой нагрузкой, хотелось бы так раз услышать про тонкости - в каких случаях лучше использовать для веб-сервиса `java`, а в каких  `php`?

Comment: А требования какие?

Нагрузка? Сколько запросов ожидается?

Что делать сервис будет?

Сколько серверов планируется? Если в финансах не ограничены и можете плодить кучу серверов и нагрузку между ними балансировать - то тогда в принципе роли нет никакой на каком языке. Хотя здесь тоже свои тонкости...

В общем опишите задачу подробнее - тогда можно будет посоветовать что выбрать в вашем случае. А так - если десяток пользователей и вся нагрузка - отправить/получить пост/сообщение, то разницы и правда нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Холиварная тема по сути своей)

Писать нужно на том, что вы понимаете или хотите выучить (если это учебно-развлекательный проект)
Или на том, подочто что проще найти исполнителей.

С точки зрения СНГ - программисты на РНР стоят дешевле и представленны в более широком ассортименте, с другой стороны среди Java-кодеров меньше дилетантов (прошу никого пишущего на РНР не обижаться, автор ответа сам регулярно пишет и пописывает на этом языке, но позволяет себе иметь именно такое мнение).

С точки зрения нагрузки на сервера, Java-шустрее, и в чем-то более гибка, чем РНР (за счет правильной многопоточности, красивого классового наследования, нормальной типизации, статических объектов). Но писать на Java - медленее чем на РНР. И c CMS'ками под Java существенно хуже, чем под РНР.

Answer (score 0):

На чем знаете, на том и пишите, разницы никакой в общем случае

Comment: Ну разница, в общем случае, может быть большой. Только этот общий случай по времени от данного вопроса отстоит очень далеко.

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютно согласен с предыдущем оратором :)

Главно на чем вы программируете.

Зная PHP изучать Java чтобы написать web-service глупо.. ровно как и наоборот :)

Comment: По моему скромному мнению, напротив, во время учебы (и не только) стоит ловить любую возможность изучить что-то новое.

Answer (score 0):

Один из смыслов веб-сервиса в независимости от языка. Так что пишите на том к чему лежит сердце или посмотрите на окружение, если окружение чисто Java - пишите под ним, а если сайт по PHP то уж понятно на чем.